# I want to dump the exact file from local file system to the HDFS

Tags: hadoop, streaming, flume

I want to dump the exact file from local to HDFS but what is happening is that flume is merging all the data from all the .gz file and writing it into one and I want to write the .gz file on hdfs on the basis of current timestamp of the system.

AGENT_CONFIGURATION

```
# Identify the components on agent agent1:
agent1.sources = agent1_source
agent1.sinks = agent1_sink
agent1.channels = agent1_channel

# Configure the source:
agent1.sources.agent1_source.type = spooldir
agent1.sources.agent1_source.spoolDir =/data/
agent1.sources.agent1_source.fileSuffix= .COMPLETED
agent1.sources.agent1_source.deserializer=org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobDeserializer$Builder

# Describe the sink:
agent1.sinks.agent1_sink.type = hdfs
agent1.sinks.agent1_sink.hdfs.path = /user/hadoop/data
agent1.sinks.agent1_sink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
#agent1.sinks.agent1_sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent1.sinks.agent1_sink.hdfs.rollInterval=0
agent1.sinks.agent1_sink.hdfs.rollSize=0
agent1.sinks.agent1_sink.hdfs.fileType =CompressedStream
agent1.sinks.agent1_sink.hdfs.codeC=gzip
agent1.sinks.agent1_sink.hdfs.rollCount=0
agent1.sinks.agent1_sink.hdfs.idleTimeout=1

# Configure a channel that buffers events in memory:
agent1.channels.agent1_channel.type = memory
agent1.channels.agent1_channel.capacity = 20000
agent1.channels.agent1_channel.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel:
agent1.sources.agent1_source.channels = agent1_channel
agent1.sinks.agent1_sink.channel = agent1_channel
```

I am having hdfs files as below format:
text1_2018-02-01.txt.gz text2_2018-02-02.txt.gz

I wanted it to store on hdfs like 
/user/hadoop/data/event_date=2018-02-01/text1.txt.gz
/user/hadoop/data/event_date=2018-02-02/text2.txt.gz
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use hdfs command copyFromLocal or put? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyFromLocal

Comment: I don't think Flume does partitions like that. At least, not without some custom code